# Does preventing CHKDSK from occurring still allow dirty bit to be set

Tags: windows-7

If I have a clean volume and execute the following command to prevent CHKDSK from occurring,

chkntfs /x c:

If a situation occurred after that and caused the need for a chkdsk on the volume, will the dirty bit still be set in the future or does that command (chkntfs /x c:) also prevent it from being set?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160963) from Microsoft it only prevents `Autochk.exe` from including the drive for a `chkdsk /f` during start-up.

*Every time Windows restarts, `Autochk.exe` is called by the Kernel to scan all volumes to check if the volume dirty bit is set. If the dirty bit is set, autochk performs an immediate `chkdsk /f` on that volume.*

and

*The chkntfs /x commands are not cumulative, the command overwrites any previous drive exclusions that have been established. In the above example, chkntfs **only disables the chkdsk checking** on drives D and E, drive C is not checked for the presence of a dirty bit.*

So it shouldn't prevent the dirty bit from being set when there is a problem. You should however check the drive regularly for this dirty bit if you exclude it because you don't get a warning at start-up anymore.